# How would I go about using an "array" in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Completely new to MySQL and SQL in general, and I can't find a good answer online.

Let's say I have a table of users, with their user info. And let's say those users have posts published, with their own post info on.

Now, I want a column of the user table to hold the posts a user has published. That looks to be impossible if the user has published multiple posts. How would I really do this? The only thing I can think of is to have the column point to its own table, but would that mean I'd have to create a separate table for every user? Can there be a separate table where the rows are the users and every column is an ID for a post, without knowing how many posts the user has beforehand?

I am very new and would like just any information that could help me.

Comment: A users table, a posts table, and a table which maps users to posts.

Comment: What would a table that maps users to posts look like?

Comment: You don't need the mapping table. The `posts` table should have an `author_id` column.

Comment: So I could make some sort of call that uses a user as a parameter, and brings you all the user's posts, by checking the author_id of every post?

Comment: Of course, `SELECT id FROM posts WHERE author_id = 123`

Comment: Thank you so much! I suppose it's noticeable that I am a regular programmer, haha

Answer (score 0):

### answer in short-"use userid in post_info table"

In user_info table minimum columns needed :-

```
Id,user_name
1,'Akhil'
2,'Suresh'
```

In post_info table minimum columns needed :-

```
post_info_Id,user_id,user_post, 
1,1,'first post of akhil'
2,1,'second post of akhil'
3,2,'first post of suresh'
4,2,'i am suresh'
```

Comment: please elaborate your question as it is not clear what you want to ask